# remove action adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove the pagination on my front page, which has a static homepage.

```
<link rel='next' href='http://domain/page/2/'/>
```

I use this code but it doesn't remove it:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 2 );
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced this down and it was a plugin issue. This code works just fine

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this ,

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 20, 2 );
```

Or you can also use ,

```
add_action( 'init','remove_some_actions' );

function remove_some_actions(){
   remove_action( 'wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 2 );
}
```

Comment: I just tried both and unfortunately it is not working.